# Какой знак препинания нужен?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-варианта

*Нам осознать потерю эту **сложно** —

Забыть нельзя, вернуть все невозможно.*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой знак препинания требуется после слова "сложно" (тире, запятая, двоеточие)?

Comment: по идее, двоеточие или запятая, было бы наоборот - было бы тире, потому что вывод. Но я могу наврать)

Comment: Запятая, пожалуй, не подойдет, здесь желательно увеличенной паузой/тире  обозначить причинно-следственные отношения. С этим справилось бы двоеточие или тире (если точно не обозначить направление связи, а это в общем случае не обязательно)...  Вот автор вопроса предлагает тире (по слуху, возможно). Какой вариант лучше... Но послушаем мнения других участников\

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нужно поставить точку, потому что предложение: ‟забыть нельзя, вернуть все невозможно” – не раскрывает и не поясняет предложение: ‟Нам осознать потерю эту сложно”. Если пауза короткая, то просто запятую.